# How to load html data into closest tr with jquery

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

I wanted to load Ajax Response's HTML data into the current table row select2. When I am using ‌ `$ (". Product_attr"). Html (data);` then the value of the second row is changing as well but the value of the first-row changing also. And when `$ (this) .parents ('tr'). Find (". Product_attr")`. Html (data); I'm using it, then it doesn't work anymore. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$(document).on("change", ".product", function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/purchase/ajax/load-attrs/',
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                'product': $(this).parents('tr').find(".product").val()
            },
            success: function (data) {
                //$(".product_attr").html(data);
                $(this).parents('tr').find(".product_attr").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row p-2" data-select2-id="22">


    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" data-select2-id="21"> <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="Du3bYZRNzK3ELyR3RtcT6jd98wN2BAWRLH44ybMdlE367txtJ766wYZAqiMs5IXa"> <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.12/css/select2.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.12/js/select2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/static/django_select2/django_select2.js"></script> <div data-select2-id="20"> <div class="form-row form-row"> <div class="form-group col-sm-2"> <div id="div_id_order_date" class="form-group row"> <label for="datepicker" class="col-form-label col-md-4 requiredField">
            Date<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div class="col-md-8"> <input type="text" name="order_date" id="datepicker" autocomplete="off" class="dateinput form-control hasDatepicker" required=""> </div> </div> </div> <div class="form-group  col-sm-3 mb-0"> <div id="div_id_purchase_id" class="form-group row"> <label for="id_purchase_id" class="col-form-label col-md-4">
            Order #
        </label> <div class="col-md-8"> <input type="text" name="purchase_id" class="textinput textInput form-control" id="id_purchase_id"> </div> </div> </div> <div class="form-group  col-sm-2 mb-0"> </div> <div class="form-group col-sm-5"> <div id="div_id_supplier" class="form-group row"> <label for="id_supplier" class="col-form-label col-md-4 requiredField">
            Supplier<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div class="col-md-8"> <div class="input-group"> <select name="supplier" data-minimum-input-length="0" data-allow-clear="false" style="width:88%;" class="form-control select2widget form-control django-select2 select2-hidden-accessible" required="" id="id_supplier" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" data-select2-id="id_supplier"> <option value="" selected="" data-select2-id="79">---------</option> <option value="1">Twinkle-fashion store</option> <option value="2">STARKING</option> <option value="3">TREBLEET Store</option> <option value="4">Jagran lingerie Store</option> <option value="5">Happiness Center Store</option>

        </select><span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default" dir="ltr" data-select2-id="78" style="width: 88%;"><span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-labelledby="select2-id_supplier-container"><span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-id_supplier-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true" title="---------">---------</span><span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></span></span><span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span> <div class="input-group-append"> <span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-plus-square"></i></span> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div>
            <div class="form-row pr-3"> <fieldset> <legend>Order Items:</legend> <table class="table"> <input type="hidden" name="PurchaseOrder-TOTAL_FORMS" value="2" id="id_PurchaseOrder-TOTAL_FORMS"> <input type="hidden" name="PurchaseOrder-INITIAL_FORMS" value="0" id="id_PurchaseOrder-INITIAL_FORMS"> <input type="hidden" name="PurchaseOrder-MIN_NUM_FORMS" value="0" id="id_PurchaseOrder-MIN_NUM_FORMS"> <input type="hidden" name="PurchaseOrder-MAX_NUM_FORMS" value="1000" id="id_PurchaseOrder-MAX_NUM_FORMS"> <thead> <tr> <th>Product</th> <th>Attributes</th> <th>Amount ($)</th> <th>Amount (৳)</th> <th>Order Qnty</th> <th>Recv. Qnty</th> <th>Cost Price</th> <th>Sale Price</th> <th>Comm.Price</th> <th>Delete</th> </tr> </thead> <tbody><tr class="formset_row-PurchaseOrder dynamic-form"> <td> <input type="hidden" name="PurchaseOrder-0-order" id="id_PurchaseOrder-0-order"> <input type="hidden" name="PurchaseOrder-0-id" id="id_PurchaseOrder-0-id"> <div id="div_id_PurchaseOrder-0-product" class="form-group" data-select2-id="div_id_PurchaseOrder-0-product"> <div class="" data-select2-id="19"> <select name="PurchaseOrder-0-product" data-minimum-input-length="0" data-allow-clear="false" style="width:100%;" class="setprice product select2widget form-control django-select2 select2-hidden-accessible" required="true" id="id_PurchaseOrder-0-product" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" data-select2-id="id_PurchaseOrder-0-product"> <option value="" selected="">---------</option> <option value="99">Strapless Lace Bra (Strapless)</option> <option value="100">Strapless Seamless Bra (Push Up)</option> <option value="101">Seamless Fitness CropTop (Strapless)</option> <option value="102" data-select2-id="94">Push Up Lace Tube Top (Push Up)</option> <option value="103">Lace Tube Top (Push Up)</option> <option value="104">Tank Top (Strapless)</option> <option value="105">Seamless V-Neck Bra (Strapless)</option> <option value="106">Seamless Meryl Traceless Tops (Strapless)</option> <option value="107">Seamless Sleeping Tube Top (Push Up)</option> <option value="108">Fitness Thread Push Up Bra (Strapless, Push Up)</option> <option value="109">Strapless Padded Bra (Strapless)</option> <option value="110">Thin Cup Push Up Bra (Push Up)</option> <option value="111">Push Up Adjustable Lace Bra (Push Up)</option>

            </select><span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default" dir="ltr" data-select2-id="93" style="width: 100%;"><span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-labelledby="select2-id_PurchaseOrder-0-product-container"><span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-id_PurchaseOrder-0-product-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true" title="Push Up Lace Tube Top (Push Up)">Push Up Lace Tube Top (Push Up)</span><span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></span></span><span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span> </div> </div> </td> <td> <div id="div_id_PurchaseOrder-0-product_attr" class="form-group" data-select2-id="div_id_PurchaseOrder-0-product_attr"> <div class="" data-select2-id="42"> <select name="PurchaseOrder-0-product_attr" data-minimum-input-length="0" data-allow-clear="false" class="setprice form-control product_attr select2widget form-control django-select2 select2-hidden-accessible" style="width:250px" required="true" id="id_PurchaseOrder-0-product_attr" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" data-select2-id="id_PurchaseOrder-0-product_attr"><option value="" data-select2-id="139">---------</option>

                <option value="">Grey32B </option>

                <option value="">Grey32C </option>

                <option value="">White32B </option>

                <option value="">White32C </option>

                <option value="">Grey34B </option>

                <option value="">Grey34C </option>

                <option value="">White34B </option>

                <option value="">White34C </option>

            </select><span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default" dir="ltr" data-select2-id="100" style="width: 250px;"><span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-labelledby="select2-id_PurchaseOrder-0-product_attr-container"><span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-id_PurchaseOrder-0-product_attr-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true" title="---------">---------</span><span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></span></span><span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span> </div> </div> </td> <td> <div id="div_id_PurchaseOrder-0-amount_usd" class="form-group"> <div class=""> <input type="number" name="PurchaseOrder-0-amount_usd" step="any" class="setprice amount_usd numberinput form-control" min="0" required="true" id="id_PurchaseOrder-0-amount_usd"> </div> </div> </td> <td> <div id="div_id_PurchaseOrder-0-amount_bdt" class="form-group"> <div class=""> <input type="number" name="PurchaseOrder-0-amount_bdt" step="any" class="setprice amount_bdt numberinput form-control" min="0" required="true" disabled="" id="id_PurchaseOrder-0-amount_bdt"> </div> </div> </td> <td> <div id="div_id_PurchaseOrder-0-order_qnty" class="form-group"> <div class=""> <input type="number" name="PurchaseOrder-0-order_qnty" step="any" class="setprice order_qnty numberinput form-control" min="0" required="true" id="id_PurchaseOrder-0-order_qnty"> </div> </div> </td> <td> <div id="div_id_PurchaseOrder-0-recvd_qnty" class="form-group"> <div class=""> <input type="number" name="PurchaseOrder-0-recvd_qnty" step="any" class="setprice recvd_qnty numberinput form-control" min="0" required="true" disabled="" id="id_PurchaseOrder-0-recvd_qnty"> </div> </div> </td> <td> <div id="div_id_PurchaseOrder-0-unit_price" class="form-group"> <div class=""> <input type="number" name="PurchaseOrder-0-unit_price" step="any" class="setprice unit_price numberinput form-control" min="0" required="true" id="id_PurchaseOrder-0-unit_price"> </div> </div> </td> <td> <div id="div_id_PurchaseOrder-0-sales_price" class="form-group"> <div class=""> <input type="number" name="PurchaseOrder-0-sales_price" step="any" class="setprice sales_price numberinput form-control" min="0" required="true" disabled="" id="id_PurchaseOrder-0-sales_price"> </div> </div> </td> <td> <div id="div_id_PurchaseOrder-0-commission_price" class="form-group"> <div class=""> <input type="number" name="PurchaseOrder-0-commission_price" step="any" class="setprice commission_price numberinput form-control" min="0" required="true" disabled="" id="id_PurchaseOrder-0-commission_price"> </div> </div> </td> <td> <div class="form-group"> <div id="div_id_PurchaseOrder-0-DELETE" class="custom-control custom-checkbox"> <div class=""> <input type="hidden" name="PurchaseOrder-0-DELETE" id="id_PurchaseOrder-0-DELETE"> </div> </div> </div> <a class="delete-row" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="pl-3 far fa-minus-square fa-2x"></i></a></td> </tr> <tr class="formset_row-PurchaseOrder dynamic-form"> <td> <input type="hidden" name="PurchaseOrder-1-order" id="id_PurchaseOrder-1-order" value=""> <input type="hidden" name="PurchaseOrder-1-id" id="id_PurchaseOrder-1-id" value=""> <div id="div_id_PurchaseOrder-1-product" class="form-group" data-select2-id="div_id_PurchaseOrder-1-product"> <div class="" data-select2-id="124"> <select name="PurchaseOrder-1-product" data-minimum-input-length="0" data-allow-clear="false" style="width:100%;" class="setprice product select2widget form-control django-select2 select2-hidden-accessible" required="true" id="id_PurchaseOrder-1-product" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" data-select2-id="id_PurchaseOrder-1-product"> <option value="" selected="" data-select2-id="116">---------</option> <option value="99" data-select2-id="125">Strapless Lace Bra (Strapless)</option> <option value="100" data-select2-id="126">Strapless Seamless Bra (Push Up)</option> <option value="101" data-select2-id="127">Seamless Fitness CropTop (Strapless)</option> <option value="102" data-select2-id="128">Push Up Lace Tube Top (Push Up)</option> <option value="103" data-select2-id="129">Lace Tube Top (Push Up)</option> <option value="104" data-select2-id="130">Tank Top (Strapless)</option> <option value="105" data-select2-id="131">Seamless V-Neck Bra (Strapless)</option> <option value="106" data-select2-id="132">Seamless Meryl Traceless Tops (Strapless)</option> <option value="107" data-select2-id="133">Seamless Sleeping Tube Top (Push Up)</option> <option value="108" data-select2-id="134">Fitness Thread Push Up Bra (Strapless, Push Up)</option> <option value="109" data-select2-id="135">Strapless Padded Bra (Strapless)</option> <option value="110" data-select2-id="136">Thin Cup Push Up Bra (Push Up)</option> <option value="111" data-select2-id="137">Push Up Adjustable Lace Bra (Push Up)</option>

            </select><span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--below" dir="ltr" data-select2-id="115" style="width: 100%;"><span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-labelledby="select2-id_PurchaseOrder-1-product-container"><span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-id_PurchaseOrder-1-product-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true" title="Fitness Thread Push Up Bra (Strapless, Push Up)">Fitness Thread Push Up Bra (Strapless, Push Up)</span><span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></span></span><span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span> </div> </div> </td> <td> <div id="div_id_PurchaseOrder-1-product_attr" class="form-group" data-select2-id="div_id_PurchaseOrder-1-product_attr"> <div class="" data-select2-id="142"> <select name="PurchaseOrder-1-product_attr" data-minimum-input-length="0" data-allow-clear="false" class="setprice form-control product_attr select2widget form-control django-select2 select2-hidden-accessible" style="width:250px" required="true" id="id_PurchaseOrder-1-product_attr" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" data-select2-id="id_PurchaseOrder-1-product_attr"><option value="" data-select2-id="140">---------</option>

                <option value="" data-select2-id="143">Grey32B </option>

                <option value="" data-select2-id="144">Grey32C </option>

                <option value="" data-select2-id="145">White32B </option>

                <option value="" data-select2-id="146">White32C </option>

                <option value="" data-select2-id="147">Grey34B </option>

                <option value="" data-select2-id="148">Grey34C </option>

                <option value="" data-select2-id="149">White34B </option>

                <option value="" data-select2-id="150">White34C </option>

            </select><span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--below select2-container--focus" dir="ltr" data-select2-id="117" style="width: 250px;"><span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-labelledby="select2-id_PurchaseOrder-1-product_attr-container"><span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-id_PurchaseOrder-1-product_attr-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true" title="---------">---------</span><span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></span></span><span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span> </div> </div> </td> <td> <div id="div_id_PurchaseOrder-1-amount_usd" class="form-group"> <div class=""> <input type="number" name="PurchaseOrder-1-amount_usd" step="any" class="setprice amount_usd numberinput form-control" min="0" required="true" id="id_PurchaseOrder-1-amount_usd"> </div> </div> </td> <td> <div id="div_id_PurchaseOrder-1-amount_bdt" class="form-group"> <div class=""> <input type="number" name="PurchaseOrder-1-amount_bdt" step="any" class="setprice amount_bdt numberinput form-control" min="0" required="true" disabled="" id="id_PurchaseOrder-1-amount_bdt"> </div> </div> </td> <td> <div id="div_id_PurchaseOrder-1-order_qnty" class="form-group"> <div class=""> <input type="number" name="PurchaseOrder-1-order_qnty" step="any" class="setprice order_qnty numberinput form-control" min="0" required="true" id="id_PurchaseOrder-1-order_qnty"> </div> </div> </td> <td> <div id="div_id_PurchaseOrder-1-recvd_qnty" class="form-group"> <div class=""> <input type="number" name="PurchaseOrder-1-recvd_qnty" step="any" class="setprice recvd_qnty numberinput form-control" min="0" required="true" disabled="" id="id_PurchaseOrder-1-recvd_qnty"> </div> </div> </td> <td> <div id="div_id_PurchaseOrder-1-unit_price" class="form-group"> <div class=""> <input type="number" name="PurchaseOrder-1-unit_price" step="any" class="setprice unit_price numberinput form-control" min="0" required="true" id="id_PurchaseOrder-1-unit_price"> </div> </div> </td> <td> <div id="div_id_PurchaseOrder-1-sales_price" class="form-group"> <div class=""> <input type="number" name="PurchaseOrder-1-sales_price" step="any" class="setprice sales_price numberinput form-control" min="0" required="true" disabled="" id="id_PurchaseOrder-1-sales_price"> </div> </div> </td> <td> <div id="div_id_PurchaseOrder-1-commission_price" class="form-group"> <div class=""> <input type="number" name="PurchaseOrder-1-commission_price" step="any" class="setprice commission_price numberinput form-control" min="0" required="true" disabled="" id="id_PurchaseOrder-1-commission_price"> </div> </div> </td> <td> <div class="form-group"> <div id="div_id_PurchaseOrder-1-DELETE" class="custom-control custom-checkbox"> <div class="">  </div> </div> </div> <a class="delete-row" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="pl-3 far fa-minus-square fa-2x"></i></a></td> </tr><tr class="dynamic-form-add"><td colspan="10"><a class="add-row" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="far fa-plus-square fa-2x"></i></a></td></tr></tbody></table> <script src="/static/js/jquery.formset.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript">
                $('.formset_row-PurchaseOrder').formset({
                    addText: "<i class='far fa-plus-square fa-2x'></i>",
                    deleteText: "<i class='pl-3 far fa-minus-square fa-2x'></i>",
                    prefix: 'PurchaseOrder',
                });
            </script> </fieldset>

            </div>
            <div class="form-row "> <fieldset class="form-group col-sm-6 shipment-block "> <legend>Order Shipment Info:</legend> <br><div class="form-row form-row"> <div class="col-sm-4"> <div id="div_id_tracking" class="form-group row"> <label for="id_tracking" class="col-form-label col-md-4">
                Tracking #
            </label> <div class="col-md-8"> <input type="text" name="tracking" class="textinput textInput form-control" id="id_tracking"> </div> </div> </div> <div class="col-sm-8"> <div class="form-group row"> <div class="offset-md-4 col-md-8"> <div id="div_id_journal_entry" class="custom-control custom-checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" name="journal_entry" class="checkboxinput custom-control-input" id="id_journal_entry"> <label for="id_journal_entry" class="custom-control-label">
                Journal
            </label> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div>
                <br><div class="form-row form-row"> <div class="col-sm-4"> <div id="div_id_status" class="form-group row"> <label for="id_status" class="col-form-label col-md-4">
                    Status
                </label> <div class="col-md-8"> <select name="status" class="select form-control" id="id_status"> <option value="AD" selected="">Awaiting delivery</option> <option value="RD">Received</option> <option value="PR">Partial Received</option> <option value="SC">Shipment Canceled</option> <option value="OC">Order Canceled</option> <option value="DS">Dispute Submitted</option>

                </select> </div> </div> </div> <div class="col-sm-8"> <div id="div_id_narrations" class="form-group row"> <label for="id_narrations" class="col-form-label col-md-4">
                    Narrations
                </label> <div class="col-md-8"> <textarea name="narrations" cols="20" rows="3" class="textarea form-control" id="id_narrations"></textarea> </div> </div> </div> </div> </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="form-group col-sm-6 "> <div class="form-row form-row"> <div class="form-group col-sm-6 pl-5"> </div> <div class="form-group col-sm-6 pl-5"> <div id="div_id_order_amount_usd" class="form-group row"> <label for="id_order_amount_usd" class="col-form-label col-md-4">
                    Amount ($)
                </label> <div class="col-md-8"> <input type="number" name="order_amount_usd" value="0" step="any" class="numberinput form-control" disabled="" id="id_order_amount_usd"> </div> </div> </div> </div>
                    <div class="form-row form-row"> <div class="form-group col-sm-6 pl-5"> </div> <div class="form-group col-sm-6 pl-5"> <div id="div_id_order_amount_bdt" class="form-group row"> <label for="id_order_amount_bdt" class="col-form-label col-md-4 requiredField">
                        Amount (৳)<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div class="col-md-8"> <input type="number" name="order_amount_bdt" value="0" step="any" class="numberinput form-control" required="" disabled="" id="id_order_amount_bdt"> </div> </div> </div> </div>
                    <div class="form-row form-row"> <div class="form-group col-sm-6 pl-5"> </div> <div class="form-group col-sm-6 pl-5"> <div id="div_id_discount_type" class="form-group row"> <label for="id_discount_type" class="col-form-label col-md-4 requiredField">
                        Discount type<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div class="col-md-8"> <select name="discount_type" class="form-control setprice discount_type select form-control" required="true" id="id_discount_type"> <option value="P" selected="">Percent</option> <option value="A">Amount</option>

                    </select> </div> </div> </div> </div>
                    <div class="form-row form-row"> <div class="form-group col-sm-6 pl-5"> </div> <div class="form-group col-sm-6 pl-5"> <div id="div_id_discount_percent" class="form-group row"> <label for="id_discount_percent" class="col-form-label col-md-4">
                        Dis. Percent
                    </label> <div class="col-md-8"> <input type="number" name="discount_percent" value="0" step="any" class="form-control setprice discount_percent numberinput form-control" min="0" required="true" id="id_discount_percent"> </div> </div> </div> </div>
                    <div class="form-row form-row"> <div class="form-group col-sm-6 pl-5"> </div> <div class="form-group col-sm-6 pl-5"> <div id="div_id_discount_amount" class="form-group row" style="display: none;"> <label for="id_discount_amount" class="col-form-label col-md-4">
                        Dis. Amount
                    </label> <div class="col-md-8"> <input type="number" name="discount_amount" value="0" step="any" class="form-control setprice discount_amount numberinput form-control" min="0" required="true" id="id_discount_amount"> </div> </div> </div> </div>
                    <div class="form-row form-row"> <div class="form-group col-sm-6 pl-5"> </div> <div class="form-group col-sm-6 pl-5"> <div id="div_id_freight_charge" class="form-group row"> <label for="id_freight_charge" class="col-form-label col-md-4">
                        Freight Charge
                    </label> <div class="col-md-8"> <input type="number" name="freight_charge" value="0" step="any" class="form-control setprice freight_charge numberinput form-control" min="0" required="true" id="id_freight_charge"> </div> </div> </div> </div>
                    <div class="form-row form-row"> <div class="form-group col-sm-6 pl-5"> <div id="div_id_debit_account" class="form-group row"> <label for="id_debit_account" class="col-form-label col-md-4 requiredField">
                        Debit account<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div class="col-md-8"> <select name="debit_account" data-minimum-input-length="0" data-allow-clear="false" style="width:100%;" class="form-control select2widget form-control django-select2 select2-hidden-accessible" id="id_debit_account" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" data-select2-id="id_debit_account"> <option value="4" selected="" data-select2-id="120">Merchandise Inventory</option>

                    </select><span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default" dir="ltr" data-select2-id="119" style="width: 100%;"><span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-labelledby="select2-id_debit_account-container"><span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-id_debit_account-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true" title="Merchandise Inventory">Merchandise Inventory</span><span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></span></span><span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span> </div> </div> </div> <div class="form-group col-sm-6 pl-5"> <div id="div_id_total_amount" class="form-group row"> <label for="id_total_amount" class="col-form-label col-md-4">
                        Total Amount
                    </label> <div class="col-md-8"> <input type="number" name="total_amount" value="0" step="any" class="form-control setprice total_amount numberinput form-control" min="0" required="true" disabled="" id="id_total_amount"> </div> </div> </div> </div>
                    <div class="form-row form-row"> <div class="form-group col-sm-6 pl-5"> <div id="div_id_credit_account" class="form-group row"> <label for="id_credit_account" class="col-form-label col-md-4 requiredField">
                        Credit account<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div class="col-md-8"> <select name="credit_account" data-minimum-input-length="0" data-allow-clear="false" style="width:100%;" class="form-control select2widget form-control django-select2 select2-hidden-accessible" id="id_credit_account" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" data-select2-id="id_credit_account"> <option value="5" selected="" data-select2-id="122">Credit Card - Standard Bank</option>

                    </select><span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default" dir="ltr" data-select2-id="121" style="width: 100%;"><span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-labelledby="select2-id_credit_account-container"><span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-id_credit_account-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true" title="Credit Card - Standard Bank">Credit Card - Standard Bank</span><span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></span></span><span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span> </div> </div> </div> <div class="form-group col-sm-6 pl-5"> <div id="div_id_paid_amount" class="form-group row"> <label for="id_paid_amount" class="col-form-label col-md-4">
                        Paid amount
                    </label> <div class="col-md-8"> <input type="number" name="paid_amount" value="0" step="any" class="form-control setprice paid_amount numberinput form-control" min="0" required="true" id="id_paid_amount"> </div> </div> </div> </div> </fieldset>

            </div>
            <div class="form-row "> <div class="form-group col-sm-10"> </div> <div class="col-md form-row"> <div class="buttonHolder form-group col-sm-2"> <span class="waves-input-wrapper waves-effect waves-light"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit-id-submit"></span>

            </div>

            </div> </div>

        </div> </form>

</div>
```

Comment: Please post your HTML as well, so it's easy to understand selector with `parent`.

Comment: I just added HTML

Comment: Hi,put `$(this)` in some variable outside ajax call i.e :`var selector = $(this)` and then use it inside your success function i,.e : `selector .parents('tr').find(".product_attr").html(data);`